# Flask-RESTful fields.List always returns None

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have two resources, `UserCollectionResource` and `UserResource`. The latter works fine and returns users as expected. The former's `get` method always returns `[{'users': None}]`. I have followed many examples and cannot figure out what is producing this behavior.

```py
user_fields = {
    'id': fields.Integer,
    'username': fields.String
}

user_collection_fields = {
    'users': fields.List(fields.Nested(user_fields))
}

class UserCollectionResource(Resource):
    @marshal_with(user_collection_fields)
    def post(self):
        args = post_users_parser.parse_args()
        test_user = UserModel.query.filter_by(username=args.username)
        if test_user:
            abort(409)
        else:
            user = User(args.username, args.password, ifttt_key=args.ifttt_key)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            return user, 201

    @marshal_with(user_collection_fields)
    def get(self):
        users = UserModel.query.filter(UserModel.username != "admin").all()
        if not users:
            abort(404)
        else:
            return users

class UserResource(Resource):
    @marshal_with(user_fields)
    def get(self, user_id=None):
        user = UserModel.query.filter_by(id=user_id).filter(UserModel.username != "admin").first()
        if not user:
            abort(404)
        else:
            return user

api.add_resource(UserCollectionResource, '/api/users', endpoint="users")
api.add_resource(UserResource, '/api/users/<int:user_id>', endpoint="user")
```

I think it is worth noting that printing `users` before the return statement shows, in fact, a list of users: `[<User(Username ='zeke')>]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with help from this [issue](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/513). `UserCollectionResource`'s `get` function needs to return `{"users": : users}` rather than `users`. This is not made obvious by the docs.